# Can force be defined as the rate of change of four-momentum in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, forces, classical-mechanics, momentum

In Newtonian physics, the force acting on a particle is defined as the rate of change of momentum
$$F=\frac{dp}{dt}.$$

Also, the force can be defined as the derivative of the potential
$$F=-\frac{dV}{dr}.$$

However, I am curious whether in General Relativity, we can define the [four-force](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Four-force) as the rate of change of the four-momentum as follows:
$$F^r=\frac{dp^r}{d\tau},$$ where $p^r$ is the radial component of the four-momentum and $\tau$ is the proper time. If this definition is correct, it would be helpful if someone provide links to relevant references.

Answer (score 3):

The equations of Special and General Relativity are often not linear like Newton's Second Law is. To fit Special Relativity, you have to modify it to the form:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}
=\gamma(\mathbf{v})^3m\mathbf{a}_\parallel
+\gamma(\mathbf{v})m\mathbf{a}_\perp,
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{a}_\parallel$ and $\mathbf{a}_\perp$ is a decomposition of the acceleration $\mathbf{a}$ into a parallel and perpendicular part to the velocity $\mathbf{v}$. You can find this derivation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_mechanics).

In General Relativity, the geodesic equation is also not linear, so you can't define such a four-force vector for gravity, but you can do so for all the other forces (for example electromagnetic ones) using said geodesic equation:
\begin{equation}
F^\sigma
=m\left(\ddot{x}^\sigma+\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\sigma\dot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu\right).
\end{equation}